# Map NERDComToggleComment to a keyboard shortcut

Tags: vimrc, plugin-nerdcommenter

To use `NERDComToggleComment`, I need to type

```
<Leader>c<Space>
```

(in my case, Leader is <kbd>,</kbd>).

I would like to map this to a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>any key</kbd> if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is reserved/unavailable for any reason).

What should I write in `.vimrc`?

I naively tried those two different approaches. None of which gave satisfaction.

```
" Call existing mapping
vmap <silent><C-c> : <Leader>c<Space>
" Call function directly
vmap <silent><C-c> :NERDComToggleComment<CR>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `<C-C>` might not be the best key combination, you can use the auxiliary mappings provided by the plugin:

```
vmap <silent><C-C> <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle
```

See also `:help NERDComMappings`.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I'm not familiar with the `<Plug>` syntax. I saw that somewhere and thought <Plug> was some sort of placeholder or example.
`

Comment: `:help NERDComMappings` returns `E149: Sorry, no help for NERDComMappings`.

Comment: Any reason not to use Ctrl+C? (When I launch a command from vim, Ctrl+C is still usable so stop the command.)

Comment: @Jérôme Maybe you didn't set up the help tags properly.
Try running `:helptags nerdcom/docdir` where `nerdcom/docdir` is the directory that contains NERDCommenter's docs and then try using `:help NERDComMappings` again.

Comment: @Jérôme No particular reason, I just try to stay clear of key combinations that are likely to cause issues at some point, though I do not know if any such problem will ever arise...

Comment: Thanks for the `:helptags` command. I didn't know about it. (And I would have expected this to be automated, with a standard for the doc location in plugins.)